# How to PAUSE app background music when Chartboost and AppLovin Video Ads is playing and resume app background music after close the Video Ad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

Dear fellow programmers/developers,

I am a total newbie and I am trying to learn some objective-c to do some simple re-skin for some app for iOS. I inherit a puzzle game source code and would like to implement a function to PAUSE the game background music when Video Advertisement from Chartboost and Applovin is playing. I successfully integrated Chartboost and AppLovin into the app but when the Video Advertisement is playing either from these 2 ad networks, the video ads sound is over-lapping with my game background music and it is very annoying to hear 2 sounds playing together. I would appreciate if any fellow developers can assist me or point me to the correct resources for answer. I am pasting a few screen shots from xcode and if I am missing anything please advice and I will paste more screen shots.

[This is my AdManager.m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nM3Jg.png)

[This is my AdManager.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zp00A.png)